# How to make template specialization inherit from generic base without causing recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I'm trying to implement matrices in my program. Square matrices should have extra capabilities like calculating the determinant, but they should also have all capabilities of a matrix. I've tried to do it this way - partially specializing the Matrix and making it inherit from a generic Matrix. I've searched on the internet but I haven't found anything like this, only with types, but it doesn't work with nontype parameters.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int b>
class Matrix {
public:
    // some functions
    void g () {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int a>
class Matrix <a, a> : public Matrix <a,a> {
public:
    void f () {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main () {
    Matrix <3,3> m;
    m.f();
   m.g();
}
```

Matrix  is actually trying to inherit from itself and I get an error

> recursive type 'Matrix' undefined | aggregate 'Matrix<3, 3> m' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: One way - just put `f` into the main template, and put `static_assert(a == b)` as the first line. An attempt to call it on non-square matrix would then produce an error.

Comment: Matrix? `std::vector<type> foo;` and access with `foo[row * num_columns + column];` or `std::vector<std::vector<type>> foo(rows)`.

Comment: @Swordfish Why? What would a determinant of a vector even mean?

Comment: @Don'tDownVote Because manual memory management is error-prone and so 1990s.

Comment: @Swordfish it's not error prone if I free all the memory in the destructor.

Comment: @Don'tDownVote Mhm. And of course you have a working assignment operator, copy c-tor and move c-tor. And implementing all that is surely worth the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with just a template class. A second template class, and some metaprogramming, is needed to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int b>
class Matrix_impl {
public:
    // some functions
    void g () {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int a>
class special_matrix_impl : public Matrix_impl<a,a> {
public:
    void f () {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<int a, int b>
struct which_template {

    typedef Matrix_impl<a, b> type;
};

template<int a>
struct which_template<a, a> {

    typedef special_matrix_impl<a> type;
};

template<int a, int b>
using Matrix=typename which_template<a, b>::type;

int main () {
    Matrix <3,3> m;
    m.f();
    m.g();
}
```

The real template names here are `Matrix_impl` and `special_matrix_impl`, and `Matrix<a,b>` selects the appropriate one.

Alternatively, the only way to do this with a single template is to use an extra, defaulted, template parameter to disambiguate the template specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int b, typename=void>
class Matrix {
public:
    // some functions
    void g () {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int a>
class Matrix <a, a, void> : public Matrix <a, a, int> {
public:
    void f () {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main () {
    Matrix <3,3> m;
    m.f();
   m.g();
}
```

Somewhat ugly, but might end up being cleaner in the end if multiple specializations will be required.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by splitting `Matrix` into two class templates.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int a, int b>
class MatrixImpl {
public:
    // some functions
    void g () {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <int a, int b>
class Matrix : public MatrixImpl <a, b> {};

template <int a>
class Matrix <a, a> : public MatrixImpl <a,a> {
public:
    void f () {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main () {
    Matrix <3,3> m;
    m.f(); // ok
    m.g(); // ok

    Matrix <3,4> n;
    n.f(); // <- invalid
    n.g(); // ok
}
```